# D3js creating x-axis with labels in months

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, graph

I am trying to create a graph for plotting height with respect to age in years using d3js in angular js.

I created a linear scale but the linear scale is in multiples of 5
 `5,5.5,6,...`

I want to create an x-axis scale as `5,5.6,6,6.6,7...18`. Here 5 will represent `January` and 5.6 will represent `June`.

Since there are 12 months when calculating the years the data is getting plotted wrongly.

for example

```
date of birth is 01-jan-2011
date of entry is 05-dec-2016
when calculating the years it is 5.11
I am unable to plot this in graph
```

I have tried passing the values as `tickValues` but the space between the ticks is irregular.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Or
Is it possible to set a major tick after every 5 minor tick.

(i.e) 5 is a major tick then `5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5` are minor ticks and 5.6 will be a major tick.

This is my graph. I don't want to show the minor tick values, but i need to plot values like 5.11,6.10 and so on.

**Edit2 :**

Now I have set the values in months like this `.tickValues(d3.range(60, 217, 6))` So the x axis values are 60,66,72... and this is equivalent to 5, 5.6, 6... in years 60 months = 5 years.

How do I show the label in years and plot the graph using the month values

Comment: What exactly are those `5.10`, `5.11`, `6.0` etc. values? Are they numbers or strings? I believe you know that `5.10` is **smaller** than `5.6`. Thus, if they are numbers, you'll have a lot of work trying to fix this.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado they are integers, if the value is 5.11, the `11` represents the month of `November`

Comment: How can `5.11` be an integer? Do you mean it is two numbers with a dot in between?

Comment: sry they are numbers just like 5.5

Comment: In that case, explain that in the question. And, once again, `5.11` is **smaller** than `5.9` or `5.6`. How do you expect the axis putting it before `6.0`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado. Is it possible to set the label as 5, 5.6, 6 just for display and internally i calculate the age in months and plot here

Comment: Well, that's **exactly** what I did in my answer, which I deleted after you said that it didn't suit you.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Pls add your answer again